# PHP simple html dom Parser - Simple Script

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

I need some help for creating a simple script that check on other site.

Example: I have index.php and an input form like this.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cf" placeholder="Codice Fiscale"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and `index2.php` where I need to get and show validation or error not found
where URL will be `index2.php?cf=FFFFF21243F1234F354F`

other URL where I need to check is: http://www.nonsolocap.it/codice-fiscale/controllo/?cf=FFFFF21243F1234F354F  (this url shows Error cuz this CF does exist)

Comment: what's your question for us?

Comment: Do you need to check for errorcodes on server or client? You could use jquery to check if the link returns an errorcode. Or in PHP use curl.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question But well.

```
action="some site.php"
```

in

```
<form>
```

Explain more--..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you are trying to get data on another url with parameter CF and then that other url will do validation using CF value

ok to do that

```
<form method="GET" action="http://yourwebsitename.php">
    <input type="text" name="cf" placeholder="Codice Fiscale"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now when you click submit then your url will look like 
http://yourwebsitename.php?cf=value-enterd-on-the-form

now on the other website where you want to do validation get CF paremeter using

```
$cf = GET['cf'];
```

now do whatever you want to do with $cf

Comment: mate thnks alot for this but i was asking help on parsing html dom cuz i get many errors when i try to use it! if anyone have a little function , just that im asking.

Comment: do you want to extract some data from a website using html simple dom parser?